# Generating a random number from a lognormal distribution

Tags: c++, random

This shouldn't be too difficult, but for some reason this sampling random numbers from a distribution is really tripping me up.

I know the best options for generating random numbers from a distribution are boost/C++11 libraries...unfortunately, I can't get this code to compile with c++0x, and anyway, I would preferably keep compatibility on a server that I'm also using, which is running gcc 4.1.2 - ancient, I know, doesn't support newer C++. Frustrations. And as always, time crunch means I need to do the best I can with a quick fix.

Taking the exponent of a random number from the box muller equations is my next option, but I'm not getting a lognormal distribution with the parameters I specify. I don't understand why this is not working.

Any help would be hugely appreciated!

```
void testRNG(){

    int mean = 5000;
    int std = 50;

    ofstream out("./Output/normal_samples.out");

    RunningStats normal;
    for (int i=0;i<2000;++i){
        double sample = randomSample(mean, std, NORMAL);//call function with box muller transformation to return a number from a normal distriubtion
        out<<sample<<endl;
        normal.Push(sample);//keep a running average of sampled numbers
    }
    cout<<"Normal Mean = "<<normal.Mean()<<endl;
    cout<<"Normal Std = "<<normal.StandardDeviation()<<endl;

    RunningStats lognormal;
    for (int i=0;i<2000;++i){
        double sample = randomSample(mean, std, LOGNORMAL);
        out<<sample<<endl;
        lognormal.Push(sample);
    }
    cout<<"Lognormal Mean = "<<lognormal.Mean()<<endl;
    cout<<"Lognormal Std = "<<lognormal.StandardDeviation()<<endl;
}
```

The sampling functions, which I didn't write, go first to a case thing from randomSample(), and then call:

EDIT - I noticed that it actually did call a function to find the lognormal parameters. Added in.

```
double randNormal(double mean, double stdev) {
static long numSamples = 0;
static double Z2;
if ((numSamples++ & 1) == 0) {
    double Z1, U1, U2;
    do { U1 = randUniform(0, 1); } while (U1 <= 0 || U1 >= 1);
    do { U2 = randUniform(0, 1); } while (U1 <= 0 || U1 >= 1);
    Z1 = sqrt(-2 * log(U1)) * cos(6.28318531 * U2);
    Z2 = sqrt(-2 * log(U1)) * sin(6.28318531 * U2);
    return mean + stdev * Z1;
} else {
    return mean + stdev * Z2;
}
}

double randLognormal(double mu, double sigma) {
return exp(randNormal(mu, sigma));
}

double randLognormalMeanStdev(double mean, double stdev) {
return randLognormal( log(mean) - 0.5 * log(1 + (stdev * stdev) / (mean * mean)) , log(1 + (stdev * stdev) / (mean * mean)));
}
```

So the output I get is:

```
Normal Mean = 4998.72 //I said 5000
Normal Std = 49.7054 //I said 50
Lognormal Mean = 4999.74
Lognormal Std = 0.492766 //this is the part that is not working
```

What am I missing to get the lognormal std to be what I want?

Other options would also be appreciated - maybe there is something else I am missing.

Thanks in advance!

Edit - I realized I should have made it clear that I need to sample from a lognormal distribution

Comment: I found the issue...it is the in randLognormalMeanStdev() function. It returns the parameter VARIANCE not the sqrt(parameter variance). Once I fixed that bug, everything is fine. I need to learn not to trust code from other people without question.....